# Restrict access to entire website

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, asp.net-identity

How can I restrict access to the root folder and all sub folders of my website?  I have an ASP.Net Webforms application using Identity for authentication.  Users will have accounts created for them. When a user goes to the website the first thing they should see is the login page.  I've tried "/", "~/", "", values in the Location tag, as well as simply not having the location tag in the web.config file but none of these produces the desired result.

```
   <location path="/">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="user1@mydomain.com"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>

   <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<location>` element and try the following config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="FormsAuth" loginUrl="/your-login-path" /> 
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    ....
</system.web>
```

There may be further adjustments you'll need to make on the `<forms>` element depending on your enviroment/setup etc, but this should get you going.

---

**EDIT**

The above doesn't work for ASP.Net Indentity. The only way I could get this to work was creating individual `<location>` elements for every page, in the root and subfolder `web.config`, explicitly denying or allowing users as needed.

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users ="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Brent, thank you very much.  I've put the following elements in my web.config and I get the error message "HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."   '  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="FormsAuth" loginUrl="/Account/login.aspx"  />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>'

Comment: @user3720699 the error tells you what the problem is... the query string is too long... what does the query string look like? Are you getting multiple redirects? Try reading through the following to see where your solution differs: https://www.google.co.nz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=implementing%20forms%20authentication%20in%20asp.net

Comment: Brent, thank you for your reply.  You are correct the query string is huge.  It looks like it is in a loop appending to the query sting adding account, login, and return url information.  In looking at the results that came up in your suggested search, I noticed that I'm getting away from one of the things I wanted to do, use ASP.Net Identity for authentication.  The path I'm heading down with these changes is simple forms authentication.  I'd like to get back to using Identity.

Comment: @user3720699 sorry I've probably pointed you in the wrong direction with this answer... I've done a little more playing at it seems the only way to get this to work is to add individual `<location>` elements for every single page, this seems to be a bit of an oversight on MS's behalf, but I guess they were focused more on the MVC implementation

Comment: Brent, no problem.  I'm grateful for your intentions.  I agree with your observations regarding the necessary use of the <location> element and MC's probable focus on MVC.  What I ended up doing was placing all my custom files and folders in a folder at the root level.  Then I identified that folder in the <location> element.  That still left some clean up work that I still doing with the files under the Account folder.  I consider what I done to be a work around so I'm not categorizing it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your Root Web.Config Add:

```
 <authorization>
  <deny users ="?"/>
</authorization>
```

In your Account/Web.Confing Add:

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

That worked for me